# The term "Homotopy" was given by whom?

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, math-history

I want to know the names who define the term '*Homotopy*' in algebraic topology in 1907.
 Are they Dehn and Paul Heegaard?

What is the full name of **Dehn**?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The Dehn who solved one of Hilbert's problems is was Max Dehn. I do not know if you are thinking of the same guy. And Heegaard's first name is Poul.

Comment: Than you you are right it  is Max Wilhelm Dehn.

Answer (score 4):

According to Jean Dieudonné, [A history of Algebraic and Differential Topology, 1900-1960](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817649069) (1989), page 43 :

> The words *homotopy* and isotopy were coined by Dehn and Heegaard in their *Enzyklopädie* article with a purely combinatorial definition adapted to their "abstract" conception of homology ([*], pp. 205-207), and they were not retained by later workers, with the 
>   exception of Steinitz.
>
> Brouwer [in 1912] seems to have been the first to give our present definition of *homotopy* ([L.E.J.Brouwer, *Collected Works*, vol. II, North Holland, Amsterdam, 1976], p. 462)

[*] The paper by [Max Dehn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Dehn) and [Poul Heegaard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poul_Heegaard), *Analysis Situs*, Enzykl. der math. Wiss., Ill 1 AB 3, 
Teubner, Leipzig, 1907.